# Daemon console app calling Azure AD cant find AppRole (MSAL)

Tags: azure, api, azure-active-directory, console-application, azure-ad-msal

I have two applications registered in Azure, a REST API and daemon console application that calls the REST API.
The work flow is shown

```
Daemon console app --call for token using secret--> Azure AD 
Daemon console app use the return token to call --> REST API.
```

I do get the token and correct AppRole is defined in REST API, with Admin consent.
however, when I try to call the REST API Daemon console app throws this error

```
Failed to call the web API: InternalServerError
Content: System.ArgumentException: Requested value 'ApplicationRole' was not found.
   at System.Enum.TryParseByName(RuntimeType enumType, String originalValueString, ReadOnlySpan`1 value, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnFailure, UInt64& result)
```

I followed the official MS documentation here
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/2-Call-OwnApi

I decoded the JWT token it has the role defined:

```
...
"oid": "xxxxx",
  "rh": "xxxx",
  "roles": [
    "ApplicationRole"
  ],
...
```

The Manifest file of REST API

```
...
appRoles": [
        {
            "allowedMemberTypes": [
                "Application"
            ],
            "description": "Daemon apps in this role can consume the web api.",
            "displayName": "ApplicationRole",
            "id": "unique uid",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "lang": null,
            "origin": "Application",
            "value": "ApplicationRole"
        }
    ],
...
```

The admin consent is also being granted to Daemon console App

```
API / Permissions name     Type          Description          Admin consent require      Status

IoT-Manager (1)  
ApplicationRole       Application    ApplicationRole           Yes                   Granted for XX
```

What could be wrong here ?

**Update**

I debug Daemon application I found out that the access token does not contain roles

```
...

AuthenticationResult result = null;

try
            {
                result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                    .ExecuteAsync();
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Token acquired \n");
                Console.WriteLine(result.AccessToken);
               
                Console.WriteLine("Token ExpireOn \n");
                Console.WriteLine(result.ExpiresOn);

                Console.ResetColor();
            }
...
```

When I print the access token and decode it shows it has AppRoles, where When I debug the object `AuthenticationResult result` has no attribute for roles.

Comment: Though you've got a 'correct' token but I still wanna check again. If you created an azure ad app(represent for service) which exposed api and add the application role? If you created another azure ad app(represent for client) which has consented the api permission which exposed just now? If you set the second app's client id and secret in the daemon application? I think I need to run the sample you provided and try to reproduce your error.

Comment: I created a REST API app in Azure which expose an API (api;//<id>) without scopes since this meant to be used by application only. and another client application in Azure that is configured to use that API.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I've tested the sample in my place, here's the working result. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bec7d.png

Comment: I've added my steps, you may compare my settings with yours to check if there's some difference, that may leads to the error. Pls feel free to share your further problems if exists :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run the sample you provided and it worked well, I'll show my steps below.

1. Creating an azure ad app as the service. When registering the app, I only enter the name field and keep others the default.
   [image]
2. Next I exposed an api in this application. Expose an API-> Add a scope-> keep the default application id url->save and continue-> edit my scope like below:

[image]

3. Add the role like screenshot below:

[image]

4. Creating another azure ad app as the client, only enter the name field too.
5. Create client secret and add api permission.

[image]

6. set the sample code, the appsetting.json file of each project are needed to modify, and  the controller file in api project. The value needed to be changed in controller depends on the api. In my side, you can see the screenshot in step 5, it shows api://xxx/App.Role, so I set the value as `App.Role`.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the issue was in the backend, I had validation at Kafka level when I recieve messages there was no applicationRole defined only User and Admin for that I had to change the name of the App.Role to (User). Thanks for help :)

Comment: Thank you for your response and your mark :)